# Android License Check (or access to a file) by .so file

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

My Android app uses both Java code and C++ code compiled in a .so file.
In a previous version of my app the Java code checked the license with Google Play servers and then wrote something to a file. The C++ lib before executing its code first checked that file to see whether the license was valid or not.

Now this is no longer possible as writing a file with MODE_WORLD_READABLE triggers a security exception and even only checking the existence of that file (created with MODE_PRIVATE) in the C++ code doesn't work.

I've read the solution should be for the Java code to provide a Content Provider to access that file but I don't think that would be possible with native C++ code, and perhaps that only works when you have two different apps?

Does anyone know a workaround to achieve what I need?

Thanks.

EDIT: to be clear there's only one app which uses Java code and comes with a C++ lib as .so file

Comment: "I know the solution should be for the app A to provide a Content Provider to an app B to access that file" -- in your first two paragraphs, there appears to only be one app, not two. If you do indeed have two apps, then I suspect that you will be better served rewriting those first two paragraphs to explain in detail what app is doing what.

Comment: There's only one app, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then, you do not need `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, and you do not need a `ContentProvider`, as both of those are for working with more than one app. You might want to consider switching gears and writing a question that has a [mcve] that shows your code for "checking the existence of that file (created with MODE_PRIVATE) in the C++ code doesn't work" and explains in detail what "doesn't work" means with respect to that code.

Comment: Why doesn't the Java program check the license and exit if the license is not found or not valid before calling the C++ ?

Comment: Because the .so lib can be called by other apps as well so it needs to check the license everytime it is loaded

Comment: _"There's only one app"_ and _"the .so lib can be called by other apps as well"_ doesn't quite add up.